# What is the way to dynamically allocate array elements in div elements so that each row will have at most N elements in pure HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, given N being 3 in each row, when more and more elements are pushed to the array, the number of rows also grows but each row will still display at most 3 elements. 
Currently I can use map to create correpdoning  for every element in the array. But the div are just on top of each others. What I really want is :
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div id="deck" style="flex: 1;width:500px;height:300px;text-align:center;background-color:green;margin:0 auto;">CARDS</div>
        <div id="discard" style="flex: 0.5 1 30%;width:500px;height:300px;text-align:center;background-color:yellow;margin:0 auto;">DISCARDS</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cards" style="background-color:orange;margin:0 auto;text-align:center">XYZ</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let cards = ["xf"];
        addCard("xa");
        function addCard(card){
            cards.push(card);
            document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML = cards.map(c => 
                `<div>
                <div id="${c}" onclick="selectCard(this)" style="width:50px;height:30px;text-align:center">${c}</div>
                </div>`
            ).join('')
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `display:grid` for starters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) & [Grid Template Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

This Snippet Might help you get a quick start.

```js
let cards = ["xf", "abc", "123", "45"];
addCard("xa");

function addCard(card) {
  cards.push(card);
  document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML = cards.map(c =>
    `<div>
                <div id="${c}" onclick="selectCard(this)" style="width:50px;height:30px;text-align:center;">${c}</div>
                </div>`
  ).join('')
}
```

```css
#cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards" style="background-color:orange;margin:0 auto;text-align:center">XYZ</div>
```